# Django: make list_display different from the actual variable

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have a django model called clown:

[image]

And I make the list of attributes show up in Django admin like this:

[image]

[image]

How do I make it so that the list in the Django Admin UI is different from the actual variable? Like let's say the variable is identification and I want it to show up as id in the administration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define method for custom representation of model fields. This must give you what you want

```
class ClownAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_id(self, obj):
        return obj.identification
    get_id.short_description = 'id'
    
    list_display('name', 'get_id', 'stupid', 'fat')
```